# postfix smtpd process bound to unix domain socket

Tags: postfix

To utilize a special cleanup daemon for outgoing emails only, I defined a special smtpd process in `master.cf` that is used as `default_transport`. (Only postfix should be able to submit emails through this daemon!)

```
127.0.0.1:10027 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix-smtpout
  -o cleanup_service_name=srscleanup
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
  -o content_filter=smtp:
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=permit
```

This works fine. However, it is open to any local user/process on the machine connecting to this port and submitting mail without authentication (due to the relaxed sender/recipient restrictions), which is not very secure.

Therefore, I would like to run this special `smtpd` as a unix domain socket (which only processes running under the postfix user can access).

I set `default_transport = smtpout` and created a service in `master.cf` like this:

```
smtpout     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix-smtpout
  -o cleanup_service_name=srscleanup
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
  -o content_filter=smtp:
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=permit
```

However, this results in emails getting stuck in the queue and log messages like this: `warning: unexpected end-of-input from private/smtpout socket while reading input attribute name`.

How can I fix this and use a smtpd process bound to a unix domain socket (instead of binding to inet)?

Comment: I'm weak on `master.cf`, but if you are running `postfix` in a `chroot`, have you placed the socket within the `chroot` and can `postfix` write to it?

Comment: @Paul Yes. I have also tried not chrooting the `smtpout` smtpd, but that didn't help either.

Comment: I'm reaching the same conclusion that I can't use a UNIX socket for the `smtpd` process, however why don't you remove the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` and `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` options so it uses the ones from main.cf? That way it doesn't open it up...not ideal though